# python tornado AsyncHTTPClient fetching request working once in thread

Tags: python, tornado

The following is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import imp
import time
import csv
import json
import uuid
import threading
import urllib
from tornado.web import StaticFileHandler
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from nitro.ioloop import IOLoop


io_loop = IOLoop()

DATA_SERVER_HOST = "192.168.0.148"


class AlertsRun(object) :
    def __init__(self, config) :
        self._DATA_SERVER_PORT = config.DATA_SERVER_PORT
        #print self._DATA_SERVER_PORT (8080)

        self._TERRA_BASE_URL = "http://%s:%s" % (DATA_SERVER_HOST, self._DATA_SERVER_PORT)
        #print self._TERRA_BASE_URL
        self._http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()

    def alerts_thread(self):
        self.call_alert_url()
        print "stackoverflow"
        threading.Timer(60, self.alerts_thread).start()

    def handle_response (self,api_response) :

        print api_response
        data = api_response.body
        print data

    def call_alert_url(self) :
        try :
            options = {}

            stream_url = "%s/alerts" % (self._TERRA_BASE_URL)
            #encoded_parameters = urllib.urlencode(options)
            print stream_url #http://192.168.0.148:8080/alerts
            self._http_client.fetch(
                stream_url, 
                self.handle_response,
                #method="POST", 
                #body=encoded_parameters,
                request_timeout=3000
            )
        except Exception, e :
            return


def main() :
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 :
        print "usage: run-server.py <config-file>"
        return

    config_path = sys.argv[1]



    config = imp.load_source("terra_config", config_path)

    alertsrun = AlertsRun(config)
    alertsrun.alerts_thread()
    io_loop.start()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

In the above code,when the call_alert_url is called for the first time I am getting the response but any subsequent calls after that results in timeout.

Following is the output:

```
http://192.168.0.148:8080/alerts
stackoverflow

HTTPResponse(_body=None,buffer=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x10a7ace30>,code=200,effective_url='http://192.168.0.148:8080/alerts',error=None,headers={'X-Consumed-Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Length': '40', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'TornadoServer/4.2.1', 'Etag': '"0f2247c8e8facfdc08ebbed85e171d0f211cbdcf"', 'Date': 'Wed, 30 Sep 2015 06:15:56 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},reason='OK',request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x10a7e2d90>,request_time=0.5350480079650879,time_info={})
{
  "data": "Done"
}

http://192.168.0.148:8080/alerts
stackoverflow

HTTPResponse(_body=None,buffer=None,code=599,effective_url='http://192.168.0.148:8080/alerts',error=HTTPError('HTTP 599: Timeout',),headers={},reason='Unknown',request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x10a6dcf10>,request_time=20.002495050430298,time_info={})
None
```

Also nitro.ioloop has tornado io_loop :

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop as TornadoIOLoop

__all__ = [
    "IOLoop"
]

class IOLoop(object) :
    NONE = TornadoIOLoop.NONE
    READ = TornadoIOLoop.READ
    WRITE = TornadoIOLoop.WRITE
    ERROR = TornadoIOLoop.ERROR

    def __init__(self) :
        self._tornado_io_loop = TornadoIOLoop()

    def inner(self) :
        return self._tornado_io_loop

    def close(self, all_fds=False) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.close(all_fds)

    def add_handler(self, fd, handler, events) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.add_handler(fd, handler, events)

    def update_handler(self, fd, events) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.update_handler(fd, events)

    def remove_handler(self, fd) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.remove_handler(fd)

    def start(self) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.start()

    def stop(self) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.stop()

    def time(self) :
        return self._tornado_io_loop.time()

    def add_timeout(self, deadline, callback) :
        return self._tornado_io_loop.add_timeout(deadline, callback)

    def remove_timeout(self, timeout) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.remove_timeout(timeout)

    def add_callback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs) :
        self._tornado_io_loop.add_callback(callback, *args, **kwargs)

    def run(self) :
        try :
            self.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt :
            print ""
            print "Ctrl-C recieved. Exiting."
```

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Looks like it's not this code that's failing, but the server isn't responding withing the 3000ms timeout. Have you tried pointing the URL to somewhere that will always at least respond like google.com?

Comment: I have tried with google.com also,it just works only once @barny

Comment: Why do you not use the [tornado io_loop](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html)?

Comment: @rebeling i am using tornado io_loop (updated the question)

Comment: using io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current() works on my machine, prints 'stackoverflow' every 60 secs

Comment: @rebeling it worked :) can you post this as answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [tornado.ioloop](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html) directly:

```
import tornado.ioloop
io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
```